Can't serialize json with one field as a Map<String, Double>
I have the following kotlin class:
data class MyClass(private val myMap: Map<String, Double>, val defaultValue: Double)

I don't have problems to deserialize it (to convert it from json string to a Kotlin class), but when I try to serialize it (from Kotlin class to json string), it does not work for the property myMap.
This is an example of a test:
private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules()

@Test
fun serializing() {
    val myClass = MyClass(mapOf(Pair("user1",1.0), Pair("user2", 2.0)), defaultPoints = 1.0)

    val myMapObject = JSONObject()
    myMapObject .put("user1",1)
    myMapObject .put("user2",2)
    val expected= JSONObject()
    expected.put("myMap", myMapObject)
    expected.put("defaultPoints", 1)
    val actual = JSONObject(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pointCalculator))

    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}

But the json field myMap in the actual json is empty (This is what I get: {"defaultPoints":1}).
Am I missing something?

I'm confused about which direction you're going.  You said serializing was OK, but the bad string ("This is what I get") implies that it is the serializing that fails.

Hi @Tim Roberts, thanks for your answer, so, maybe I am confusing serializing and deserializing, so from a kotlin class to a json string it works, from json string to kotlin class it does not work

I updated the post, hopefully it is more clear now

Why is myMap private?  I don't know the exact details, but it seems like that would prevent JSONObject from seeing that field.

@Tim Roberts, myMap is private for no reason, as you said, I removed the private part and now it works. Thanks!

If your aim is to take your Kotlin object, serialize into a String and then deserialize it back into an object and asset that this round trip works, then you do not need JSONObject.  The actual fault (as @Tim Roberts) says is due to the private modifier on the myMap field.  By default Jackson will look for public getters for rather than use direct field access, so it cannot see the myMap field.
This code works:
data class MyClass(val myMap: Map<String, Double>, val defaultPoints: Double)
private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules()

@Test
fun serializing() {
    val myClass = MyClass(mapOf(Pair("user1",1.0), Pair("user2", 2.0)), defaultPoints = 1.0)
    val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass)
    println(json)
    val myClassRoundTrip = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass::class.java)
    assertEquals(myClass, myClassRoundTrip)
}


and it prints
{"myMap":{"user1":1.0,"user2":2.0},"defaultPoints":1.0}


I also wanted to test the round trip, the problem was with the private identifier in my map. Thanks!
